# Sonarqube ignore test execution data

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm trying to import generic test execution with `sonar.testExecutionReportPaths`.
I'm using the xml file format  provided in the doc.
I use full path to the file in the path attribute. And files exist.

I don't understand why my files are ignored. Any idea ?

```
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CI\Sonarqube.xml"
sonar.test.inclusions = "**\*Test*.cs"
```

Here is the log from Sonar Runner:

```
INFO: Sensor Generic Test Executions Report
INFO: Parsing C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CI\Sonarqube.xml
WARNING: WARN: Property 'sonar.genericcoverage.unitTestReportPaths' is deprecated. Please use 'sonar.testExecutionReportPaths' instead.
INFO: Imported test execution data for 0 files
INFO: Test execution data ignored for 5 unknown files, including:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CI\Tests\A-Test.cs
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CI\Tests\B-Tests.cs
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CI\Tests\C-Tests.cs
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CI\Tests\D-Test.cs
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CI\Tests\E-Test.cs
INFO: Sensor Generic Test Executions Report (done) | time=265ms
```

Here is the a part of the Generic XMl File:

```
<testExecutions version="1">
  <file path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CI\Tests\A-Test.cs">
    <testCase name="My A Test" duration="1210" />
  </file>
  <file path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CI\Tests\B-Tests.cs">
    <testCase name="My B Test" duration="566" />
  </file>
</testExecutions>
```

Thank you!

Comment: When you look at `A-Test.cs` in the SonarQube UI, how does the path displayed for it compare with the path in your report?

Comment: It does not appear. I don't know if it's related to sonar.test.inclusions=**\*Test*.cs. I don't want thoses files to be included on metrics.

Comment: It probably does not work, because the path in the `file` element does not match the file known to SonarQube.

Answer (score 9):

What did it for me was adding:
`sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=coverage/test-report.xml
sonar.tests=src
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts` to my sonar-project.properties file. "sonarqube-scanner-node".

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to confirm those parts if you want to make the sonar unit test count show correctly, it must be one of the error

- Add config `sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=xx/test-report.xml` to properties and make sure the path is correct.
- Check your `test-report.xml` `file` field and `path` content(`file path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CI\Tests\A-Test.cs"`), make sure the path is the same as the file in your local or server, for example, if you run this inside docker, you need to check the `A-Test.cs` file path in the docker container, whether it's the with the defined path in xml file.

Finally, I solved my problem by doing this check, hopefully, it can help you. 
And there are some tips from standard documentation [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/generic-test/)

```
* The root node should be named testExecutions.
* Its version attribute should be set to 1.
* Insert a file element for each test file. 
* Its path attribute can be either absolute or relative to the root of the module.
```

BTW, there is a warning in your sonar log:

```
WARNING: WARN: Property 'sonar.genericcoverage.unitTestReportPaths' is deprecated. Please use 'sonar.testExecutionReportPaths' instead.
```

But I can see you already use the `testExecutionReportPaths`, you may need to check whether sonar run the lasted version of settings and the option `soanr56x` is false in your package.json config.